# List.Contains() doesn't detects a string

Tags: c#, list

As the title says my list "Cvqt" contains different strings for example `"1 maxHearts Player"` and I'm trying to check if it contains `" maxHearths " + name` (which is already set whenever something enter's the method as Player) and i have tried to but break point there and it show's Player so this is not problem but it will simply jump over the if statement's.. Here's the code

```
if (Cvqt.Contains(" maxClubs " + name))
{
    Cvqt.Remove(maxClubs.ToString() + " maxClub " + name);
}
else 
{
    maxClubs = j;
    Cvqt.Add(maxClubs + " maxClubs " + name); 
}                           
if (Cvqt.Contains(" clubs " + name))
{
    Cvqt.Remove(clubs.ToString() + " clubs " + name);
    clubs--;
}
else 
{
    Cvqt.Add(clubs + " clubs " + name); 
}
```

Comment: are you sure about the spaces before and after `maxClubs`? also note that the search is case sensitive.

Comment: Then it probably doesn't contain the string. Have you tried to debug and see what's in the list?

Comment: are you sure about casing? Have you looked at using IndexOf? This would allow you to directly remove an item if there is a valid index.

Comment: i tried without the spaces still the same even thought i dont think this should be a problem because the List has spaces anyway and yes i have tried to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Contains` on a `List<string>` it only checks if the list contains a string that is a ***exact match*** to what you are passing in, it will not do a partial match.

If you want partial matches you need to do something more complicated like

```
if (Cvqt.Any(x=>x.Contains(" maxClubs " + name)))
{
    Cvqt.Remove(maxClubs.ToString() + " maxClub " + name);
}
```

or

```
var item = Cvqt.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(" maxClubs " + name));
if (item != null)
{
    Cvqt.Remove(item);
}
```

if you want to remove the found item instead of the specific string using `maxClubs`.

What those two methods do is call [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) on each item instead of [`List<T>.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) on the entire list, which is what you where doing. Doing a `List<T>.Contains(T t1)` is the same as doing a `Object.Equals(T t1, T listItem)` on each item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Contains as it pertains to a List object looks for the entire string in a list of strings.

You are looking for "max clubs" as a substring.  That is the "Contains" off the string object

Example:

```
List<string> x = new List<string>(){"Hello", "goodbye"};
bool y = x.Contains("good"); // will be false
y = x.Contains("goodbye"); // will be true

y = x[0].Contains("Hell"); // will be true
```

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
List<string> stringsWithMaxClubs = Cvqt.Where(argString => argString.Contains(" maxClubs " + name)).ToList();
```

Comment: well it will get a lot harder if i want to check for the entire string is there a way to check for just "max clubs " ?

Comment: You can iterate through the list with Linq. (see edit... though it looks like a lot of others have posted a similar solution that is probably a lot closer to what you're actually looking for)

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains strings in the form of `maxClubs + " maxClubs " + name` while you're searching for `" maxClubs " + name`. There will be no element in your list that exactly matches this (unless `maxClubs` is an empty string).

You can use Linq [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for what you want:

```
if (Cvqt.Any(x => x.Contains(" maxClubs " + name)))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate ! I will test it out and if it works i will mark this as an answer :)